# Finding Interior/Exterior of a Set in C

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I want to find the interior of the following set but I'm having difficulties nailing down the proof:

$U={z∈C:Rez≥Imz}$

I think the interior should be V={z∈C:Rez>Imz} and I have a rough sketch of the proof I'm trying to do:

Let z be an arbitrary point in C such that Rez > Imz (i.e. z∈V). Let ε= Rez - Imz > 0.

For all x ∈ D (z,ε), we try to show Rex > Imx and therefore x ∈ U and D (z,ε) ∈ U and so V is interior of U.

But I'm having trouble showing this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Make a picture, you will see that your choice of $\epsilon$ is not suitable. You have to take $\epsilon$ to be at most $(\mathrm{Re}(z)-\mathrm{Im}(z))/\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @arnett Thanks for the pointer! I also realized since I couldn't easily introduce Imx into the inequality, I should do two separate inequalities and show that i)Re(x)>(Re(z)+Im(z))/2 and ii) Im(x)<(Re(z)+Im(z))/2